# Sort a list with a element still in last position

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have list of objects with data. I want the the particular object alone to stay last in the list when I am doing sorting. 
But its coming at the very first now.

Present:

**Archived**
Application
Run - time etc
Embedded Components  IDE -
Debug, Compile and Build Tools
Initialization/Boot/Device Driver

Required

Application
Run - time etc
Embedded Components  IDE -
Debug, Compile and Build Tools
Initialization/Boot/Device Driver
**Archived**

```
Collections.sort(existingList,new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {
  public int compare(Map<String, Object> o1,Map<String, Object> o2) {
    String archiveCheck = (String)o1.get("name");
    if(archiveCheck.equalsIgnoreCase("Archived"))
        return -10000;
    else
        return ((String) o1.get("name")).compareTo((String) o2.get("name"));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just return positive value whenever `o1` is `Archived`

```
Collections.sort(existingList ,new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {
        public int compare(Map<String, Object> o1,Map<String, Object> o2) {
           String name1 = (String)o1.get("name");
           String name2 = (String)o2.get("name");

           if(name1.equalsIgnoreCase("Archived"))
             return 1;
           if(name2.equalsIgnoreCase("Archived"))
               return -1;
           return name1.compareTo(name2);
        }
    });
```

**Edit**
We have to check the `Archived` value for both arguments in the Comparator. Updated the answer. So, in case of second argument matching Archived, then return negative value

Comment: Thanks. but this is not working .. actually it sorts in alphabetic order and "Archived" comes as 2nd in the list

Comment: @NishanthGandhidoss We have to check the `Archived` value for both arguments in the Comparator. Updated the answer

Comment: Yes it did.. Thanks :)

Comment: Wow, very good solution

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution could be to remove the element you want to keep last from your list (or not add it in the first place), sort the list with its default comparator, then add the element at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The most simply thing, but not such as effective as you probably need, which occurred to me is the idea about

- to iterate over `original list`- `"Archived"` copy to some `temp`, all
  others copy to `newList`..
- `Sort newList`, and for the last insert
  `"Archived"` object (temp)